# How to Created Nested JSON objects in SOLR?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I am dumping data in SOLR database. Earlier I was using Elastic Search and it was allowing me to store nested JSON objects.

Is there any way I can dynamically create nested JSON values when inserting in SOLR?

I am using JAVA as a backend language. My code is:

```
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("UUID", eventID);
document.addField("eventCategory", eventCategory);
.
.
.
.
document.addField("source", source);

I want something like this: 
{
"UUID":"1",
"source":abcd,
"eventCategory": {
    "event1":"a",
    "event2":"b",
    "event3":"c"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solr is a collection of flat schema documents. You can add dynamic field to solr but it does not support nested JSON object.

But you can use nested documents specified in following resource.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html

But querying on child documents is not as straightforward as ElasticSearch or MongoDB.

Comment: Yeah! I also could not find anything similar to this. Maybe I need to make some different collection and map keys accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [addChildDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_4_0/solr-solrj/index.html?org/apache/solr/common/SolrInputDocument.html) to add the nested doc to the parent one. So code would be:

```
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("UUID", eventID);
document.addField("eventCategory", eventCategory);
...
SolrInputDocument child = new SolrInputDocument();
...
document.addChildDocument(child);
```

Comment: I tried doing this. It does not create the Nested JSON. Do you have some sample code in which you have done this?